# Apache и виртуальные хосты по сети

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Стоит xampp windows и настроены виртуальные хосты по типу

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@db
    DocumentRoot "ПУТЬ"
    ServerName db
    ServerAlias db
</VirtualHost>
```

Также прописаны строки в hosts

```
127.0.0.1       db
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем: как по сети вызвать любой виртуальный хост. Сейчас если подключиться к wifi (к которому подключён и мой компьютер с локальным сервером) с телефона, например, автоматически перенаправляет на первый виртуальный хост, который с компьютера доступен по двум именам `localhost/` и `db/`. Второй виртуальный хост (например `second/`) не представляется возможным вызвать с мобильного. Как достучаться до него? Никаких настроек ни в `vhosts` apache и `hosts` windows я не прописывал для `localhost/`.